# Run command at startup as root

Tags: linux

I would like to run a command (that turns off bluetooth devices) at every startup. I normally use cron for these, but this is a command that needs to be ran as root. How do I do this?

Comment: If you don't want bluetooth, why don't you just disable the bluetooth service?

Answer (score 5):

You can still use cron to do it.

make an entry in /etc/crontab like this

```
@reboot  root /path/to/your/command
```

or as root type

```
crontab -e
```

and make an etry like:

```
@reboot /path/to/your/command
```

The /etc/crontab is the global crontab and thus you need to specify the user, crontab -e invokes the per-user crontab.

Answer (score 3):

As you are already using cron, you can use `@reboot` as the time specification for a cron entry.  On Debian/Ubuntu, the entry could be in a file in the `/etc/cron.d` directory.

I use the blueman tools to configure Bluetooth services. Configuration should be sticky.

If you want to completely disable Bluetooth, you should consider using `systemctl` to `disable` and `stop` the Bluetooth and blueman-mechanism services.  Disabling will prevent starting the services on reboot, and stopping will kill any currently running services.

Original/Obsolete:  You could try putting the commands in `/etc/rc.local`.  Commands in this file should be run at the end of the boot sequence.

Disabling the drivers, and or software as has been described by @skrewler is often a good solution.

Comment: Using `/etc/rc.local` is outdated (Source: https://linuxhint.com/use-etc-rc-local-boot/).

Answer (score 1):

You're looking to modify your `init.d` scripts / setting. This can get complex and depends on your distro. You might be able to edit or create `/etc/init/bluetooth.conf` or `/etc/defaults/bluetooth`. But I think Vixie Cron supports cron jobs for root and has a start up time setting.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Fedora run this `chkconfig --level 12345 bluetooth off`